# Death Rate From

Tags: phrase-meaning, modifiers

In this [article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/to-your-health/wp/2014/03/17/death-rate-from-colorectal-cancer-falling-more-rapidly-study-shows/)  :

> Black people continue to suffer a vastly disproportionate ***death rate from the disease***, the review shows.

The preposition "from" seems to go with "death" not "rate".   So, would replacing "death rate from" with "rate of death from" be better?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either one, *death rate* or *rate of death*. They are the same thing. *Death rate* however is the more common one.

The *death* in *death rate* is a noun that is acting as an adjective. It's called an attributive noun.

The *from* belongs to *death rate* as a whole, not just to *death*.

Comment: I don't much like the implications of that first sentence. Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disproportionate+death+rate%2Cdisproportionate+rate+of+death&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisproportionate%20death%20rate%3B%2Cc0), a *disproportionate rate of death* has virtually no currency (a mere [37 instance in total](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22disproportionate+rate+of+death%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), in the entire Google Books corpus).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, _death rate_ has 591 hits in the [COCA corpus](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/); _rate of death_ has 22. They clearly have the same meaning, and both are used by native speakers. I did say that _death rate_ is more common.

Comment: Becase the word *disproportionate* won't occur all that often, perhaps my previous NGram didn't underline the relative prevalences so clearly. But looking at [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+death+rate+was%2Cthe+rate+of+death+was&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20death%20rate%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20rate%20of%20death%20was%3B%2Cc0) it's hard to say OP's suggested "improvement" has much going for it as even a "credible" alternative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I didn't agree that it was an improvement. I would say that _death rate_ is better because it is more common. But the fact is that both "X rate" and "rate of X" are standard forms in the English language.

Comment: Well, I've made my point. If you want to defend the exact phrasing of your first two sentences despite my concerns over the implications (that the two forms are largely "equivalent" in terms of suitability), there's nothing more I can usefully say on the matter. But given OP is only asking the question because he thinks his version is *better*, that doesn't seem to me to be the right way to respond.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, okay, concern noted!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  So, "from" be separated from "death" is not a major concern, because I usually hear "death from some disease"?

Comment: @meatie: Your citation doesn't have *death* as the primary noun - it's talking about a *death **rate***, where *death* is effectively an adjectival usage that must go next to the primary noun *rate*. The *from the disease* bit is just an (optional) trailing modifier telling us more about that *[death] rate*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But "death rate from the disease" reads like the data (rate) is from the disease.

Comment: @meatie, that is correct. _From_ means _because of_ here. They are suffering from a high death rate because of the disease. The disease is causing a high death rate. Think of _death rate_ as a single word if you like: _death-rate_. The high _death-rate_ is from (caused by) the disease. You are right that we could also say, "rate of death-from-the-disease," and we could also group it like this: "rate-of-death from the disease." The meanings are slightly different, but they amount to the same thing in the end. "Rate-of-death from the disease" can be rewritten as "Death-rate from the disease".

Comment: @Dangph Let me clarify things.  "Death rate from the disease" reads like the data (death rate) is ***calculated*** from the disease.

Comment: @meatie, I don't think _calculated_ is the right word. _From the disease_ is acting as an adjective. It describes _death rate_. (It is a called a prepositional phrase, if you are interested.) Black people suffer a high death rate. What sort of death rate? From car crashes? No. From drowning? No, from the disease that we are talking about. Again—what sort of death rate? The death rate from the disease.

Comment: @Dangph Assuming "dropout" means the act of dropping out (possibly from school).  Does that mean this:  

"the ***dropout*** rate ***from*** school"

is okay?

Comment: @meatie, yes, that sounds fine to me. For example: "The dropout rate from school for 15-year-olds was 17%."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would "the death rate ***of*** the disease" be less controversial?

Comment: @meatie: I'm not sure what you mean by "less controversial" there. Two native speakers (myself and Dangph) are agreed that *rate of death* is in fact less commonly used than *death rate* in your context (and that the latter is "better"). See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=death+rate+from+cancer%2Cthe+death+rate+of+cancer%2Cthe+cancer+death+rate&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeath%20rate%20from%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20death%20rate%20of%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cancer%20death%20rate%3B%2Cc0) for more.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Continued in another [thread](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28869/escape-plan-from-prison).